# date command appears to ignore locale settings

Tags: locale, date, internationalization, environment

What I want to do is set a locale environment variable (`LC_TIME`, I think) to something which makes `date` output in a nice ISO format.

From looking at some other Stack Exchange questions and answers like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/17118/how-do-i-set-the-date-format-to-iso-globally-in-linux), it seems I'm on the right track, and that using the `en_DK` locale should do what I want.

But `LC_TIME=en_DK date` still gives me the same date format as I had before. I also tried setting `LANG` and `LC_ALL`, and setting them to `en_DK.UTF-8` too, and they have no effect. Just as a sanity check, I then tried setting all these things to `ru_RU` or `ru_RU.UTF-8` since these would have a more obvious effect, but still no change.

I found that there's a package called `language-pack-ru` and installed that, and also ran `sudo update-locale` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, but still no change. I didn't find a `language-pack-dk`. My `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` file has `en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8`, `en_DK.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15`, `en_DK ISO-8859-1`, so as far as I can tell I should be set.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `date` command without arguments outputs the locale's "date_fmt", which is not in ISO 8601 format in the en_DK locale. You can get the desired output by adding a FORMAT argument - something like:

```
LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8 date +'%x %X'
```

Please see [man date](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/date.1.html) for further FORMAT sequences.

Answer (score 0):

For ISO-formatted dates, `date` also has a `-I` option:

> ```
> -I[FMT], --iso-8601[=FMT]
>        output  date/time in ISO 8601 format. FMT='date' for date only (the default),
>        'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', or 'ns' for date and time to the
>        indicated precision.
> ```

The precision can be abbreviated: `-Ih` instead of `-Ihours`, etc.

```
$ date -I
2021-04-04

$ date -Ih
2021-04-04T17+02:00

$ date -Im
2021-04-04T17:37+02:00

$ date -Is
2021-04-04T17:37:34+02:00
```